# running browser on startup in full screen mode?

Tags: android, blazor, chromium, android-tv

i want to run an website on android tv by default like kiosk mode. When the user will turn one the tv it will open a browser in full screen mode with a fixed url. how can i achieve it ? the website is made with blazor server.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach is to code a basic Android app which displays your website inside a WebView but also starts on certain system events such as ActionBootCompleted, ActionReboot or ActionPowerConnected. You don't need to register for all intents, but I've found not all events are fired on all versions of Android.

This code is in C# because it's code for a Xamarin app, but you can easily convert this to Java/Kotlin if needed.

```
namespace SampleMobileApp
{
    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true, DirectBootAware = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted, Intent.ActionReboot, Intent.ActionPowerConnected })]
    public class StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            //Lets start the app
            Intent appIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
            appIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            context.StartActivity(appIntent);
        }
    }
}
```